# Defunct child process in perl TCP server

Tags: perl, sockets

I tried to create a TCP Server using Perl. I am able to successfully create the TCP Server to cater the client request. But i am facing an issue due to defunct child process. All the child processes become defunct after finishing execution. I am unable to fix the issue.

```
    my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new
   (
    LocalAddr    => 'localhost',
    LocalPort    => 48005,
    Type         => SOCK_STREAM,
    Reuse        => 1,
    Listen       => 5
    ) or die "could not open port\n";

warn "server ready waiting for connections.....  \n";

my $client;

while ($client = $server->accept())
{
   my $pid;
   while (not defined ($pid = fork()))
   {
     sleep 5;
   }
   if ($pid)
   {
       close $client;
   }
   else
   {
       $client->autoflush(1);
       close $server;
       &printClient();
   }
}

sub printClient
{
   warn "client connected to pid $$\n";
   print $client "Test";
   exit 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to call `waitpid()` to clean up the zombie when it exits.

Comment: where I should call waitpid() function in parent process or child process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid zombie processes (shown as "defunct" in listings) you have to acknowledge that they have stopped using the wait function. If you're not interested in their exit status on most Unix platforms it's enough to set the handler for SIGCHLD to IGNORE at the start of the program:

```
$SIG{CHLD}='IGNORE';
```

For a more detailed discussion see the signal handling part here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html